# How many ways of choosing 6 types of ice cream?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a simple problem to resolve, but my answers doesn't fit the one in the book.

> One shop has 11 different types of icecream. In how many ways can a customer pick 6 icecreams, not necesarily distinct?

Thanks

Comment: What are your ideas so far?

Comment: Maybe Arrangements of 11 picked by 6? I m not very good at this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Imagine the picking process. For your first choice, you can pick 11 possible ice-creams.  For your second choice, you can pick 11 possible ice-creams.  For your third choice, you can pick 11 possible ice-creams ... and so on.

Now after making your first choice, that's 11 possible situations you can be in, meaning you picked either flavor 1, flavor 2, flavor 3 ... etc.

After you make your second choice, you can be in 11 times 11 possible situations because 11 situations result from your first choice, and 11 possible second choices lead from each of your first choices.

Comment: So, the right answer is (11)^11 ? .

Comment: On the right track. It's $11=11^1$ after one choice, $11^2$ after two choices.  It would have to be $11^{11}$ after eleven choices.  You are not making eleven choices here though.

Comment: Oh right, (11)^6 it is :D . Thanks very much!